# Can two array be traversed through one for-each loop?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have two array say ..

```
String[] a = {
    "dog", "cat", "turtle"
 };
String[] b = {
    "doog", "caat", "tuurtle"
 };
```

And I traverse like

```
for (String s: a) {
Sop(s).
}
```

like wise again we need to traverse the second Array.
But my Qsn is using one enhanced for loop (for each loop) can I traverse or do some operation using two of the arrays.

Your help would be appreciated..

Comment: No. a for-each loop is only for a single collection.

Comment: you could just use an ordinary indexed for loop if both arrays are guaranteed to have the same length

Comment: through one for each loop, no. each for each iterates over one single array/list/set.

through a normal for loop, yes, but then you need to make sure that you keep possible problems in mind, like the arrays don't have the same size.

Comment: No. You should probably have a single array of Animal objects, each with a shortName and a longName fields. Parallel objects usually are a sign of bad OO design.

Comment: It is not possible to iterate two arrays using one enhanced for loop.But you can use normal index loop to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int n=0; n<2; n++)
{
   a[n];
   b[n];
}
```

But in this case u have to know array length and arrays have to have a same size

or

```
if(a.length == b.length)
{
   for(int n=0; n<2; n++)
   {
       a[n];
       b[n];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible with for-each loop. But you can have multiple indexing in for loop. Something like this

```
    String[] a = {"dog", "cat", "turtle"};
    String[] b = {"doog", "caat", "tuurtle"};

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < a.length || j < b.length; i++, j++) { 
        if(i < a.length){
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
        if(j < b.length){
            System.out.println(b[j]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @clcto : No. In that case the loop ends when the shortest array finishes iteration. The other array may still have value.

Comment: Oh just saw you checked later in the loop again.

Comment: Thanks all for try to make me understood :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in for each loop. but you can traverse through simply index base loop as other answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] a = {
"dog", "cat", "turtle"
};
String[] b = {
"doog", "caat", "tuurtle"
 };
```

And I traverse like

```
if(a.length==b.length){
 int i=0;
for (String s: a) {
Sop(s);
Sop(b[i++]);

}  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no language construction for doing this but you can implement it. Build an iterator over the to structures with two fields...